# Get my AD groups info from SharePoint Online App JS

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, office-365, rest, azure-ad

How can I to get my AD groups info (Id, Name), from an app js on SharePoint Online?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Azure AD?

Comment: @BharatKhunti, yes I'm using Azure AD

Comment: then you can use Microsoft Graph API. It's best option to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do LDAP lookups with JS. However, with the Graph API, you can do [CRUD operations on Azure AD Groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/groups-operations?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). JavaScript examples are included in the article.

Active Directory groups may be synchronized with Azure AD, depending on how Azure AD Connect was configured.